# If array includes text, display name

Tags: javascript, javascriptcore

This is a 2 part question. I am in the process of learning JavaScript ES6 / JavaScriptCore and I am trying to display a folder name if part of the name contains certain text and if it’s a directory.

The below code currently displays all the children and tells me if it’s a directory by adding true, it’s also looking to see if the child’s name contains the ClientName.

This works to a degree. Unfortunately it logs all the children when I only want to see the matches and secondly the line (else if) (where I am trying to find if its a directory and if the ClientName matches) doesn’t work.

Here are my variable logs so you know what’s what

```
2020-08-12 16:40:25: {}
2020-08-12 16:40:25: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Batman
2020-08-12 16:40:25: ABC Group, The
2020-08-12 16:40:25: true | ABC Group, The (ABCG01)
2020-08-12 16:40:25: true | Hello Dave
2020-08-12 16:40:25: false | hello you.md
2020-08-12 16:40:25: true | Hello Paul
```

It outputs true if it’s a directory and false if it’s a file.

Here’s my code so far:

```
let fmCloud = FileManager.iCloud()
let strPath = fmCloud.bookmarkedPath("Batman")
let ClientName = "ABC Group, The"
console.log (fmCloud)

console.log (strPath)

console.log (ClientName)


fmCloud.listContents(strPath).forEach( function(p_strPath)
{
  let hello = fmCloud.isDirectory(strPath + "/" + p_strPath) + " | " + p_strPath
  console.log(hello)

if (p_strPath.includes(ClientName)) console.log('Client exists')
  else if (p_strPath.includes(ClientName) & hello.includes == true ) console.log('Client exists and is a directory')
  else console.log('Client does not exist or is not a directory')
})
```

Here’s my variable logs after the JavaScript is submitted.

```
2020-08-12 17:05:13: {}
2020-08-12 17:05:13: /private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Batman
2020-08-12 17:05:13: ABC Group, The
2020-08-12 17:05:13: true | ABC Group, The (ABCG01)
2020-08-12 17:05:13: Client exists and is a directory
2020-08-12 17:05:13: true | Hello Dave
2020-08-12 17:05:13: Client does not exist
2020-08-12 17:05:13: false | hello you.md
2020-08-12 17:05:13: Client does not exist
2020-08-12 17:05:13: true | Hello Paul
2020-08-12 17:05:13: Client does not exist
```

The second part of my question is, instead of looking for I.e A ClientName how could I search for  I.e. 4 unknown characters that come after ‘(‘ I.e. (ABCDEFG) I would like to find ABCD?

Comment: Your code looks like it works exactly as it's written - it logs `Client exists and is a directory` which means your `else if` works fine. Where are you telling it to only log the matches? Right now `console.log(hello)` is not in any condition, meaning it runs unconditionally for every element.

Comment: The issue is that it’s display everything, I only want it too display the Client name that matches and nothing else

Comment: Then put the code that displays the client name inside the if-statement checking if it matches. You already have the if-statement, what's stopping you?